# get oldest metric name from prometheus by timestamp label and show it on grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a few metrics with this format:

```
vm_instance_info{creation_time="2024-03-01T14:22:13.545Z", name="some_name"}
vm_instance_info{creation_time="2024-03-02T14:22:13.545Z", name="some_name1"}
vm_instance_info{creation_time="2024-03-03T14:22:13.545Z", name="some_name2"}
```

I'm trying to create a panel on grafana with the name of the oldest vm. I tried max and topk but with now success.
I'm also trying to create an alert if the timestamp is older than 7 days.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it (neither sorting, nor alert): Prometheus is not equipped to deal with values in the labels.

General rule of thumb: if you want to apply some operations to the label itself, other than string modification, you are doing it wrong. Most likely you need to reconsider your metrics and introduce what is currently in the label as a value.

In your case, you probably should introduce metric `vm_instance_created` with label `name` and value as Unix time of creation. If you'll do this, your application of `topk` will yield expected result, and also alert will be possible with simple `vm_instance_created - time() > 7 * 24 * 60 * 60`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will follow this.